# Q : Spring Server How to avoid spawning to server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, server

I create a Spring serever with the conroller services daos and etc...

However if a client send multiple request in same time ir just relly fast, the spring start these requests -  At the same time (in parallel) that not wat i whant, i happy that my server take some requset and do it parallel BUT i whant that my server will execute all the request from same client Serially only.

There a implement in spring for that ? Maybe not and you have idea how to implement such thing ?

Any help or explanation welcome.

Just to know. each of my cliens have 'user' with unique id. i use hibernate with mysql

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Why do you want to prevent parallel request handling to happen?

Comment: thanks for your question, i create a game app. in my game, if player have 100 gold, he can buy one ship. but if he spawning buy ship request this is can make a problem, like add to him ship before update is gold. its clear that i will make my client to make sure this is impossible, but for safty

Comment: This should be handled by transactions, in the database. Not at the request-handling level.

Comment: thank you , after some search and checks, i was convincent that your solution is the best and the right solution for this problem. i will implemetion it by hibernate lock, if sombody have same problem you can see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html)